# How to create a library from multiple sub-modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module, setup.py

I'm trying to build a library with multiple sub-modules. The general structure looks like so:

```
package_test/
|___ setup.py
|___ README
|___ package_name/
|___|___ __init__.py
|___|___ submodule/
|___|___|___ __init__.py
|___|___|___ superawesome.py
|___|___ submodule2/
|___|___|___ __init__.py
|___|___|___ prettyokay.py
```

The goal is to allow a user to do something like:

```
from package_name.submodule import superawesome
from package_name.submodule2 import prettyokay
```

The `__init__.py` for each submodule currently contains (or the appropriate name for submodule2):

```
from .superawesome import superawesome
__all__ = ['superawesome']
```

The `__init__.py` for inside package_name contains:

```
__version__ = 'v0.0.alpha'
__all__ = ['submodule','submodule2']
```

When I attempt to use this, iPython shows this error:

```
From package_name.submodule import superawesome
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-03be4241edd5> in <module>()
----> 1 from package_name.submodule import superawesome

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name.submodule'
```

My `setup.py` currently contains:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
  name = 'package_name',
  packages = ['package_name'], # this must be the same as the name above
  version = '0.1.1',
  long_description=open('README').read(),
)
```

I need help figuring out how to do the layered importing structure in order to properly import the submodules as part of the whole module. This is clearly a contrived naming set, but in the real problem, each submodule contains a set of modules that belong together... but all of the submodules together are necessary for the library; so I really want to maintain this structure.